# Using SED in a shell script

Tags: shell, sed, cygwin

I have two issues that I am seeking help with.  I am using Cygwin and a Unix newbie.

1) I have a shell script that executes SED command.     In my script called master.sh, I have the following

```
    sed -nrf remove.sed < code.tp4 > code.tp5
```

remove.sed has one line

```
    / INCLUDE /d
```

When I execute the script via the following command

```
bash master.sh
```

I get the following error

```
master.sh: line 12: $'\r':command not found
```

I have no clue on what is throwing this error.

2) My 2nd issue is that the output file "code.tp5" ends up "code.tp5?".  However, using Windows explorer, the question mark appears to be
unprintable characters.  The most confusing part of this is that I get no errors when I execute this via the command prompt.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: `master.sh` and `remove.sed` have DOS line endings. Use `dos2unix` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`sed -nr s/\r//;/ INCLUDE /d' < code.tp4 > code.tp5; sed 's/$/\r$/' code.tp5`

The command 's' is for substitution. '\r' carriage return. So `s/\r//` will replace carriage return to nothing. After that you will remove the lines that contains the pattern '/ INCLUDE /d'. And with this: `sed 's/$/\r$/' code.tp5` finally you will add again the carriage return so will became again a DOS text file (`$` means end of line on a regular expression) . (Unix line endings are only new line, and DOS cas carriage return and newline).